# C++ OpenGL Quaternion for Camera flips it upside down

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, orientation, quaternions

It does look at the target when I move to the target to the right and looks at it up until it goes 180 degrees of the -zaxis and decides to go the other way.

```
Matrix4x4 camera::GetViewMat()
{
    Matrix4x4 oRotate, oView;
    oView.SetIdentity();

    Vector3 lookAtDir = m_targetPosition - m_camPosition;
    Vector3 lookAtHorizontal = Vector3(lookAtDir.GetX(), 0.0f, lookAtDir.GetZ());
    lookAtHorizontal.Normalize();

    float angle = acosf(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f).Dot(lookAtHorizontal));
    Quaternions horizontalOrient(angle, Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    ori = horizontalOrient;
    ori.Conjugate();
    oRotate = ori.ToMatrix();

    Vector3 inverseTranslate = Vector3(-m_camPosition.GetX(), -m_camPosition.GetY(), -m_camPosition.GetZ());
    oRotate.Transform(inverseTranslate);

    oRotate.Set(0, 3, inverseTranslate.GetX());
    oRotate.Set(1, 3, inverseTranslate.GetY());
    oRotate.Set(2, 3, inverseTranslate.GetZ());
    oView = oRotate;

    return oView;
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, why do you extract the forward, right and up vectors. You can just get a 3x3 rotation matrix from the the camera's inverse orientation (expressed in a quaternion) and extend it to a 4x4 matrix to incorporate its negative position. No need for all these traditional direction vectors.

Comment: Im not extracting but creating them.  Anyways im trying to figure out how can I create a quaternion so the camera looks at a target and also figuring out how i can avoid gimbal lock.  Itried many different ways and im just lost now on what im doing wrong.

Comment: As you're creating those vectors, you're taking the cross product with (0,1,0), which means you can't look straight up, which is possibly just as bad as gimbal lock. If instead you retrieve the quaternion rotating the camera from default orientation to the target object, and use that as rotation matrix as I said earlier, the camera is free to look anywhere. I can dig in one of my projects and setup a sample code as an answer if you want. EDIT: its hard to find anything wrong in your code so I can't give you a direct answer as to what is wrong.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the reply.  How would you go about creating a camera to rotate to look at the target at all times.  I gave it a shot earlier and didnt work.  I wouldnt mind you giving an example.  Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Invalid about the matrices multiplication with oRotate and TranslateOrigin.  I thought it was doing the same thing but anyways I edit my post above at the end to see if I understand what you are saying

Comment: Oh one of my comments seems to have disappeared in the edit. Well a couple things: remove the degrees -> radians conversion, its already in radians. Second, I think you forgot to invert the quaternion before converting it to the rotation matrix. Third, to be honest, I'm not sure if multiplying the matrices works, I think it SHOULD, but either way you can simply edit the 3 entries in the matrix which will cause the translation, which is many times faster than actual multiplication. As for the actual translation vector, I think you also forgot rotating it by the original inverse rotation....

Comment: ... *resumes last comment* read the code in my answer carefully and try to get every error in your code out of it, you make small but many mistakes in the maths ;)

Comment: Ok,  ill update you with the new code I have now.  Ill erase everything from my top post and put in the new code.  Anyways I also figured something out when debugging the angle.  You point a vector in the -zaxis but when it reaches the 180 degrees of that -zaxism it decides to go the other way for some reason.  This is the one im talking about:  float angle = acosf(Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f).Dot(lookAtHorizontal));

Comment: Oh yes that is actually correct. You see the dot product is not really an 'angle measurement tool', it just happens to correspond to a certain cosine of a certain angle, which ranges from -1 to 1. But when you cross the 180 degree mark, the cosine curve should continue by going up. But when you use acos() to get the actual angle, it only takes the inverse cosine of the area within -1 and 1, so instead it will 'ping pong' its way from -1 to 1 to -1 and so on...

Comment: ... You can fix this by inverting the axis to rotate around when creating the quaternion, according to the right hand rule (google images) the rotation should go the other direction instead. I haven't done much with interpolation and quaternions, so this will need some experimentation on your part, but when not interpolating it SHOULD not give much of a problem.

Comment: Hmm I see, alright then.  Well then that means it is working, I just have to figure out how to go the other way around.  Ill keep experimenting with it and searching online for that and I see where I go from there.  Thanks for replying and sticking with me this entire time.  I appreciated :).

Comment: Oh actually one last note. I believe you can simply invert the quaternion afterwards (conjugate) to get the same rotation, only in the opposite direction, since it'd only invert the x,y,z components. So in your GetViewMat() method you can simply disable the Conjugate() call to make it rotate the opposite direction instead. You may need to experiment with what angle to input though.

Comment: Yeah im trying to figure out how to do it.  I read that you have to take the dot product of the two quaternions and check whenever its negative.  Is the dot product of the quaternions is x*x + y*y + z*z + w*w?  I searched online and showed many different things.  Just want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, the conjugate of a quaternion would represent the same rotation, only in the opposite direction, if the dot product of the two is negative, it means the rotation is the 'long path' instead of the 'short path', at least if I recall correctly.

Comment: Alright I was finally able to get the yaw working.  Now I uncommented the pitch one and now I am at the same position I was at when I posted this question.  When the camera rotates up and passes the 90 degree mark, it decides to flip to the other side.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Solve it the same way you did with the yaw. Either conjugate the quaternion, or inverse the rotation axis or whatever you did last time ;)

Comment: I thought that was the problem at first but actually that doesnt really solve it.  It doesnt ping-pong like the yaw did.  The difference is that when you pitch up and pass the 90 degree mark, is turns upside down like the up vector of the camera turns negative or something but even after passing it still goes where it suppose to but just flips upside down.  If you still confused what I am talking about you can play this simple game that someone posted that has the same problem like im having when pitching up. http://orgoquest.com/unitytest/rotationtest.html

Comment: i meant to say that the camera up vector wants to stay in the posivite up and doesnt like going to the negative up

Comment: Ooh I see what you mean. It should in fact do that, the quaternion nor the matrix don't know of any limit. If you don't want the user to look further up or down than 90 degrees, you should limit the angle. In this case I think you can simply clip the dot product to 0 if its negative, that way the angle will be clipped to 90 degrees max.

Comment: I see.  So there is no way to fix that to make it work?  The game I am making is a space shooter which can kind of suck if you have a limited angle rather flying around freely.  If there is no way than oh well.

Comment: @Jose Please take this discussion to chat.

Comment: @Invalid Please take this discussion to chat.

Comment: Since I have no clue how to invite someone to a created room, an OpenGL chat I just created for this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15677/opengl

Answer (score 2):

As promised, a bit of code showing the way I'd make a camera look at a specific point in space at all times.

First of all, we'd need a method to construct a quaternion from an angle and an axis, I happen to have that on pastebin, the angle input is in radians:

http://pastebin.com/vLcx4Qqh

Make sure you don't input the axis (0,0,0), which wouldn't make any sense whatsoever.

Now the actual update method, we need to get the quaternion rotating the camera from default orientation to pointing towards the target point. PLEASE note I just wrote this out of the top of my head, it probably needs a little debugging and may need a little optimization, but this should at least give you a push in the right direction.

```
void camera::update()
{
    // First get the direction from the camera's position to the target point
    vec3 lookAtDir = m_targetPoint - m_position;

    // I'm going to divide the vector into two 'components', the Y axis rotation
    // and the Up/Down rotation, like a regular camera would work.

    // First to calculate the rotation around the Y axis, so we zero out the y
    // component:
    vec3 lookAtHorizontal = vec3(lookAtDir.x, 0.0f, lookAtDir.z).normalize();

    // Get the quaternion from 'default' direction to the horizontal direction
    // In this case, 'default' direction is along the -z axis, like most OpenGL
    // programs. Make sure the projection matrix works according to this.
    float angle = acos(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f).dot(lookAtHorizontal));
    quaternion horizontalOrient(angle, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    // Since we already stripped the Y component, we can simply get the up/down
    // rotation from it as well.
    angle = acos(lookAtDir.normalize().dot(lookAtHorizontal));
    if(angle) horizontalOrient *= quaternion(angle, lookAtDir.cross(lookAtHorizontal));

    // ...
    m_orientation = horizontalOrient;
}
```

Now to actually take `m_orientation` and `m_position` and get the world -> camera matrix

```
// First inverse each element (-position and inverse the quaternion),
// the position is rotated since the position within a matrix is 'added' last
// to the output vector, so it needs to account for rotation of the space.
mat3 rotationMatrix = m_orientation.inverse().toMatrix();
vec3 inverseTranslate = rotationMatrix * -m_position; // Note the minus

mat4 matrix = mat3; // just means the matrix is expanded, the last entry (bottom right of the matrix) is a 1.0f like an identity matrix would be.

// This bit is row-major in my case, you just need to set the translation of the matrix.
matrix[3] = inverseTranslate.x;
matrix[7] = inverseTranslate.y;
matrix[11] = inverseTranslate.z;
```

**EDIT** *I think it should be obvious but just for completeness, .dot() takes the dot product of the vectors, .cross() takes the cross product, the object executing the method is vector A, and the parameter of the method is vector B.*

Comment: Alright thanks for this.  Once i get home i will give this a shot and ill let you know how it went.  Is the Inverse the same thing as Conjugate?

Comment: Yes, in this case inverse and conjugate are the same.

Comment: Alright, well I have it implemented.  It does look at the target at the beginning but once i start moving the target it doesnt anymore.  It doesnt rotate the camera at all.  Im debugging it to see if i find the problem.

Comment: after debugging i found one problem, wouldnt the dot product of this give you the same result at all times? float angle = acos(vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f).dot(lookAtHorizontal));  The dot product of both of them will give the same number every time which is 90 degrees, in radians is 1.57 which is what I get.

Comment: Oh! Stupid mistake, should've been vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), I said along the -z axis but for some reason I decided to type in the -y axis, fixed the post. Nice job on noticing that btw :P

Comment: Its fine everyone makes mistakes.  Its a hard thing to spot though but debugging it helped so now its rotating on its yaw.  It doesnt work too well because the camera rotates beyond the target or sometimes it just decides to rotate the wrong way.  Probably may be rotating too fast?

Comment: It sounds like you're either working in a wrong space or some method like the quaternion to matrix algorithm is bugged. Make sure you work in the regular right handed coordinate system OpenGL usually uses. Also make sure you know whether your matrices are row major or collumn major. And of course when you calculate the direction (m_targetPoint - m_position) you have  to make sure they are in the same space as well. I'd need a little bit more code around what I've given to see whats going wrong.

Comment: alright I added the code so you can see.  Been working on it, messing with numbers and Im still stuck.